# Jpa/Hibernate - Is it possible to get a tree of the same entity multiple times using query parameters

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-boot

My table `service` can have references of its own entity multiple times. To get the tree of services I need to use query parameters.

I want to do it only configuation/annotation based if this is possible. At the end I want a service which contains another service which contains another service.

The connection between each service is like this:

A Service contains a `name, location, region.`

Service1 has a `location`. This location should match with the `name of service2`. `Service2` has a `region` and this region should match with the `name of service3`.

Here just the first two parts of the query:

```
@Transactional
public interface ServiceRepository extends CrudRepository<Service, Long>{

    @Query("SELECT s1, s2 FROM Service s1, Service s2"
            + " WHERE"
            + " s1.name = :serviceLocationName"
            + " AND s1.serviceType = :location"
            + " AND s1.area = s2.name"
            + " AND s2.serviceType = :region")
    public List<Service> testLocationRegion(
            @Param("serviceLocationName")String serviceLocationName,
            @Param("location")String location,
            @Param("region")String region);
}
```

This is my entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "SERVICE")
public class Service {

    public Service(){
        super();
    }

    //should be the mapping
    @OneToOne(mappedBy="service", fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private Service serviceRegion;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private Service service;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "ID", nullable = false)
    private long id;

    @Column(name = "TITLE", insertable = false)
    private String title;

    @Column(name = "NAME")
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "LOCATION", insertable = false)
    private String location;

    @Column(name = "REGION", insertable = false)
    private String region;

//...
```

Is there a way to achieve this configuartion/annotation based and if not how can I implement this with `jpql` or `hibernate criteria`.

My expected result should be a tree of services.

```
service 
|
 -> serviceLocation
    |
     ->serviceRegion
```

Any suggestion is appreciated

I tried it also with @JoinColumn. But got not a working example.

Comment: Have a look at @JoinColumn.

Comment: @HannoBinder I tried with `@JoinColumn` but did not work for me. Do you have a example base on my question?